# Как изменить стиль в NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

Я новичок в Java, да и в программировании вообще. Начал её изучать, сейчас разбираюсь с GUI, пишу простенький калькулятор, но почему то в GUI билдере мой скелет выглядит так:[image: guibuilder], а на практике - вот так:

[image: на практике]

Как это решить?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

Answer (score 2):

Стиль при разработке GUI приложений на **Java** с использованием **Swing** определяется с помощью `LookAndFeel` - темы, отвечающей за отображение и поведение элементов.

По умолчанию используется тема `Metal`, именно её вы видите на втором скриншоте.
Если не устанавливать тему специально, то именно она будет отображаться.

Всё это вытекает из того, что для обеспечения кроссплатформенности в Swing решили отрисовывать, все элементы с нуля, а не пользоваться системными.

Последний способ же был использован в AWT и не возымел успеха, так как набор инструментов определялся пересекающимся множеством, а т.к. Java запускалась и на очень ограниченных платформах с точки зрения графического интерфейсов, то набор инструментов был минимален.

Поэтому на данный момент в Swing всё рисуют с нуля.
Вид, отличный от интерфейса Windows, скорее всего связан с авторскими правами.
Хотя говорят, что на виртуальных машинах под Windows есть такой же **LookAndFeel** имитирующий системный и его можно получить с помощью:

```
javax.swing.UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
```

На моей десятке работает.

Сразу же показываю как его установить:

```
  try {
      //получаем системную тему
      String systemLookAndFeelClassName = javax.swing.UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
       //устанавливаем её
      javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(systemLookAndFeelClassName);
  } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

После описанных действий лично у меня LookAndFeel стал аналогичен тому что нарисовано в билдере.

---

Стоит отметить что помимо кросплатформенных `AWT` и `Swing` существует также зависимые от платформы решения, в частности `SWT`, которое отображает графический интерфейс системными средствами. Для любителей нативного интерфейса - отличное решение, но за него придётся поплатиться разными сборками, под разные платформы.

---

**UPD #1**

У комментаторов возник вопрос: *куда вставлять указанный в ответе код*.
Отвечаю: *в данном случае я вставлял его непосредственно в точку входа в приложение - метод **main***

ниже код формы:

```
public class TestForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public TestForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
       //код инициализации формы опущен за ненадобностью
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        try {
            String systemLookAndFeelClassName = javax.swing.UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
            // устанавливаем LookAndFeel
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(systemLookAndFeelClassName);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // Код с объявлением свойств формы также опущен        
}
```

Comment: Добрый день.
не совсем понятно, в какую часть кода прописывать ваш пример для отображения интерфейса как в билдере? Вставляя в свой фрейм у меня по коду возникают ошибки и он не компилится.

Comment: @Святослав, Вы можете выложить код своего фрейма и стектрейс? даный код, насколько я помню, я писал также во фрейме. Пришлите ссылку на код фрейма и стектрейс - разберемся

Comment: @Святослав , извиняюсь за дезинформацию. Посмотрел код того проекта -  данный код я вставлял непосредственно в точку входа в приложение - в метод main. Обновлю ответ.

Comment: @Святослав , обновил ответ. Если не поможет - смотрите мой первый комментарий и присылайте Ваш фрейм со стектрейсом.